# TCL: Backslash issue (regsub)

Tags: regex, tcl, backslash

I have an issue while trying to read a member of a list like `\\server\directory`
The issue comes when I try to get this variable using the `lindex` command, that proceeds with TCL substitution, so the result is:

```
\serverdirectory
```

Then, I think I need to use a `regsub` command to avoid the backslash substitution, but I did not get the correct proceedure.

An example of what I want should be:

```
set mistring "\\server\directory"
regsub [appropriate regular expresion here]
puts "mistring: '$mistring'"  ==> "mistring: '\\server\directory'"
```

I have checked some posts around this, and keep the `\\` is ok, but I still have problems when trying to keep always a single `\` followed by any other character that could come here.

UPDATE: specific example. What I am actually trying to keep is the initial format of an element in a list. The list is received by an outer application. The original code is something like this:

```
set mytable $__outer_list_received
puts "Table: '$mytable'"
for { set i 0 } { $i < [llength $mitabla] } { incr i } {
   set row [lindex $mytable $i]
   puts "Row: '$row'"
   set elements [lindex $row 0]
   puts "Elements: '$elements'"
}
```

The output of this, in this case is:

```
Table: '{{
   address \\server\directory
   filename foo.bar
}}'
Row: '{
   address \\server\directory
   filename foo.bar
}'
Elements: '
   address \\server\directory
   filename foo.bar
'
```

So I try to get the value of address (in this specific case, `\\server\directory`) in order to write it in a configuration file, keeping the original format and data.
I hope this clarify the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want substitutions, put the problematic string inside curly braces.

```
% puts "\\server\directory"
\serverdirectory
```

and it's not what you want. But

```
% puts {\\server\directory}
\\server\directory
```

as you need.

Comment: Tnaks for the answer, the problem is that I cannot print directly using the curly braces, as I receive this variable directly from a list using lindex.
In this case, if I try to use puts with the variable name, the output is the variable name itself.
Is there a way then, to print the content of the variable with {} using puts? This would of course be the simplest solution.

Comment: Then, the problem is where your list is defined. As another example, if you use `lindex "l1 l2 \\server\directory l3" 2` it won't work; but if you use `lindex {l1 l2 \\server\directory l3} 2` it will.

Comment: I mean: somewhere in your program, you will have something like `set mylist [list l1 l2 \\server\directory l2]` and somewhere else, you have `lindex $mylist 3`. Then, if you use `set mylist [list l1 l2 {\\server\directory} l3]`, it will work.

Comment: You are totally right about that. Unfortunately, I don´t set the initial list directly on my programm, I don´t have the control of this list but receive it as a parameter from an outer application (and this is actually the issue...).
Any ideas about it? Is there a way to read somehow different from lindex or avoid this backslash substitution?

Comment: Are you sure the outer application sends the right value? Otherwise, please update your question with some code which explains how you read that value.

Comment: I have updated now with the specific code, hope this clarify my question. Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: The rows aren't lists, they're strings. Use `split` on them.

Comment: How could I split in this case keeping the original format of this element?

Comment: Make a copy, then split the copy :)

Comment: Just to clarify, the workaround was a mixture of your solutions. Of course, treating the list as a string (what it actually was) was the first step.
Instead of spliting using the split command, I have used a regexp to solve it and avoid the annoying blank spaces elements and so on, here you have a post related to this issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020690/how-to-remove-unwanted-charecters-using-split-in-tcl
Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is fundamentally a problem on Windows (and Tcl always treats backslashes in double-quotes as instructions to perform escaping substitutions) you should consider a different approach (otherwise you've got the problem that the backslashes are gone by the time you can apply code to “fix” them). Luckily, you've got *two* alternatives. The first is to put the string in `{`braces`}` to disable substitutions, just like a C# verbatim string literal (but that uses `@"`this`"` instead). The second is perhaps more suitable:

```
set mistring [file nativename "//server/directory"]
```

That ensures that the platform native directory separator is used on Windows (and nowadays does nothing on other platforms; back when old MacOS9 was supported it was much more magical). Normally, you only need this sort of thing if you are displaying full pathnames to users (usually a bad idea, GUI-wise) or if you are passing the name to some API that doesn't like forward slashes (notably when going as an argument to a program via `exec` but there are other places where the details leak through, such as if you're using the dde, tcom or twapi packages).

Answer (score 0):

A third, although ugly, option is to double the slashes. \\ instead of \, and \ instead of \, while using double quotes. When the substitution occurs it should give you what you want. Of course, this will not help much if you do the substitution a second time.